# Socket Programming : client stops responding after sending 3 messages to the server

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.6

I'm quite new to socket programming, and I was wondering why the client stops responding after I send 3 messages to the server. Basically I send a message twice and the server responds to the client. The third time, the client just runs infinitely and the server doesn't receive anything.

Does it have something to do with overload? How does that work, especially with socket.listen()

Here is the code for reference:

client.py

```
# Import socket module 
import socket                

# Create a socket object 
s = socket.socket()          

# Define the port on which you want to connect 
port = 12345                

# connect to the server on local computer 
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', port)) 

while True:

    msg = input("Enter your message: ")

    if msg != "quit":
        s.send((msg).encode())

    else:
        # close the connection 
        s.close()      

    # receive data from the server 
    new_msg = (s.recv(1024).decode())
    print ("[CLIENT]: ", new_msg)
```

server.py

```
# first of all import the socket library 
import socket                

# next create a socket object 
s = socket.socket()          
print ("Socket successfully created")

# reserve a port on your computer in our 
# case it is 12345 but it can be anything 
port = 12345                

# Next bind to the port 
# we have not typed any ip in the ip field 
# instead we have inputted an empty string 
# this makes the server listen to requests  
# coming from other computers on the network 
s.bind(('', port))         
print ("socket binded to %s" %(port)) 


# a forever loop until we interrupt it or  
# an error occurs 
while True: 

    # put the socket into listening mode 
    s.listen(20)      
    print ("socket is listening")

    # Establish connection with client. 
    c, addr = s.accept()      
    print('Got connection from', addr) 

    msg = c.recv(1024).decode()

    if msg == "quit":
        # Close the connection with the client 
        c.close() 
    else:
        print ("[SERVER]: Recieved data: ", msg)

    print ("[SERVER]: sending", msg)

    c.send((msg).encode())
```

Answer (score 0):

You still need a better understanding on how a listening socket works:

- it listens only once
- it accepts only once *per connection*
- it can read and send as many packets as required until either side closes the connection
- at that point (and for a single threaded server) it is ready to *accept* a new connection

You server.py should become:

```
...
s.bind(('', port))         
print ("socket binded to %s" %(port)) 

# put the socket into listening mode 
s.listen(20)      
print ("socket is listening")

# a forever loop until we interrupt it or  
# an error occurs 
while True: 

    # Establish connection with client. 
    c, addr = s.accept()      
    print('Got connection from', addr) 

    while True:
        msg = c.recv(1024).decode()

        if len(msg) == 0:          # the client does not send anything but just closes its side


            # Close the connection with the client 
            c.close()
            print('Client disconnected')
            break
        else:
            print ("[SERVER]: Recieved data: ", msg)

        print ("[SERVER]: sending", msg)

        c.send((msg).encode())
```

A small fix for the client side:

```
    ...
    if msg != "quit":
        s.send((msg).encode())

    else:
        # close the connection 
        s.close()
        break           # break out of the loop after closing connection
```

But that is not all: TCP is a stream protocol. You should be prepared for packets send from one side to be splitted or re-assembled before reaching other side. The only guarantee is that bytes arrive in same order that they were send, but not necessarily in same packets.

Comment: If I wanted to accept multiple connections at once, would I need to incorporate multi-threading?

Comment: There are 2 ways for a server to accept multiple connections. The simple one is multi-threading or multi-processing. Using `select` can be an efficient alternative way, but it is slightly more complex.

Comment: @SergeBallesta hi do you mind having a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74191884/expo-app-connection-with-nodejs-stops-working-with-sockets